# Cisco 3600 not allocating DHCP addresses

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

We've purchased a cisco router 3600 for use as a DHCP server and I have configured it to test like this:

```
Current configuration : 1292 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
no ip dhcp use vrf connected
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.50
!
ip dhcp pool DHCPSERVER
   network 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 10.0.0.1 
   dns-server 8.8.8.8 
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip auth-proxy max-nodata-conns 3
ip admission max-nodata-conns 3
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!         
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
! 
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!         
ip forward-protocol nd
ip route 2.2.2.0 255.255.255.0 FastEthernet0/0
ip route 172.16.0.0 255.255.255.0 FastEthernet0/0
ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 FastEthernet0/1
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!         
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35535/discussion-on-question-by-albos-erik-cisco-3600-not-allocating-dhcp-addresses).

Comment: i cant chat before,why u give -2 reputation?

Comment: I didn't. I just moved over the comments to chat so its neater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above post, Albos_erik was having an issue with a DHCP server running on a Cisco router on FastEthernet 0/1.   The DHCP scope was 10.0.0.1, with address exclusions going from 10.0.0.1-10.0.0.50.

The example network

[image]

The issue was DHCP was not being picked up by the client connected to the same switch as the router.

One of the many things I suggested as a fix was to make sure that if he was using a managed switch to connect, check that the config on the managed switch was cleared out to be sure that there were not any VLANs or ports that were administratively shutdown that were blocking the host from picking up an address.

In the end, the OP responded in the comments to let me know that in fact the switch was the thing stopping the DHCP request between the router and the PC.

I suggested OP run the following commands on the managed switch to clear out the config.

```
Switch#  erase startup-config
Switch#  reload
```

which clears out the startup config and then reboots the switch.   Note to anyone having a similar issue, make sure you have permission to wipe the config on a managed switch before running the above commands.   If you are unsure about what you are doing, leave a comment on this question - I check SuperUser regularly.